# Batch file to check file existence by certain time

Tags: batch-file

New to batch scripting. Trying to write a script which checks for files with filename starting with LEND by polling a directory and if the file is not received by 17:30, then write a log message to log file. I have written the below batch script, the script runs fine as long as there are no files in the directory. As soon as I put files in there, it stops running. And restarts if I delete the files from that directory. Could you please advise where I am going wrong?
Thanks

```
@echo off

set I=0
set log=C:\logs\alerting.log

:recurse
for /f %%P in ('dir /b "C:\incoming\LEND*"') do (call :countfiles)
set Time=%time:~0,5%
echo Filecount: %I% at Time: %Time% >> %log%
if %Time%==17:30 goto OUT
pause 60
goto :recurse

:countfiles
set /a I+=1

:OUT 
if %I%==0 echo LEND Files not received >> %log%
EXIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code goes from countfiles to exit. Try this:

```
:countfiles
set /a I+=1
goto:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

There were actually several flaws - reusing the time variable, expecting pause to be used as a delay, the time frame could have been missed in the test, and other more minor things.

This is tested as far as the file counting goes but not the 17:30 branch

I changed the style of a few commands and variable names (I is too much like l and i and 1 in many fonts)

```
@echo off

set log=C:\logs\alerting.log

:loop
for /f %%P in ('dir /b "C:\incoming\LEND*" 2^>nul ^| find /c /v "" ') do set c=%%P
set now=%time:~0,5%
echo Filecount: %c% at Time: %now%
echo Filecount: %c% at Time: %now% >> %log%
if %now:~0,2%%now:~3,2% GTR 1730 goto :OUT
ping -n 60 localhost >nul
goto :loop

:OUT 
if %c% EQU 0 echo LEND Files not received >> %log%
EXIT
```

Comment: Thanks foxidrive. 
I used your code and it doesnt run at all. I made a small change to my code and that seemed to have worked the magic so far:

    for /f %%P in ('dir /b "C:\incoming\LEND*"') do (set /a I+=1) 

and got rid of ":countfiles".

Comment: I had a typo in the code.  Try it now - I tested it and it's working here for file counting.  You need to test the branch at 17:30